# How to allow or deny notification of microphone and camera popup in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on the **Allow** button of access camera authentication popup in Firefox browser using Selenium `WebDriver` with Java.

Below is the code which is using:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);        
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false); 
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);


FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Here is the look of popup:

[image]

Comment: @Ratmir Asanov I tried with the code 
prefs.put("permissions.default.microphone", 1);
prefs.put("permissions.default.camera", 1) but this does not work for me

Comment: Try it out with `FirefoxOptins`. It's working for me. Let me know about the results.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following preferences (in this case to allow):

```
...
options.addPreference("permissions.default.microphone", 1);
options.addPreference("permissions.default.camera", 1);
...
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I am using these options to my firefox driver, it's perfectly working

```
public static FirefoxOptions setFireFoxOptions() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
    return options;
}
```